# Using pip in Docker container leads to ReadTimeoutError

Tags: docker, pip

I try to install a package via pip. However, every usage of pip, which needs an Internet connection (even the upgrade below) leads to a ReadTimeoutError. My basic Dockerfile which is working on another system is as follows:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN wget google.com
RUN pip3 -V
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Line two shows shows that I have an Internet connection. Output:

```
Connecting to google.com (216.58.206.14:80)
Connecting to www.google.com (108.177.126.103:80)
index.html           100% |*******************************| 10582   0:00:00 ETA
```

Line three shows that pip is installed. Output:

```
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)).
```

However, line four leads to:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=100.0)",)': /simple/pip/
```

I already tried to:

- reinstall Docker
- increase the default timeout with "--default-timeout=100" (which is why the read timeout is 100 in above's error message.)

I read that there are problems with pip when you are behind a Proxy, which is not the case here. Do you have any other ideas what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: didn't face this 2 months back but facing it now

Comment: without docker the pip3 works for me, but not inside docker

Comment: change your internet connections and it might work!

Answer (score 7):

This may also be caused when your host's network interface uses a smaller than default MTU (which is usually 1500), and the docker container does not know about this and uses a larger MTU.

We  faced this on a Gitlab runner that was connected to a VLAN (MTU of 1400). Connections to some hosts worked just fine but some gave persistent issues (amongst which: PyPI, resulting in the error mentioned here).

The solution was to change the MTU for docker and all problems went away.

`/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "mtu": 1400
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After this the docker service needs to be restarted: sudo service docker restart

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions:

1. This may not be a problem with network:
   I just found a solution in another place:
   Please add two lines after **From** layer

```
ENV http_proxy http://proxy-chain.xxx.com:911/
ENV https_proxy http://proxy-chain.xxx.com:912/
```

Or change to another mirror source:
Add the following commands before **pip install**

```
RUN mkdir ~/.pip && \  
cd ~/.pip/  && \  
echo "[global] \ntrusted-host =  pypi.douban.com \nindex-url = http://pypi.douban.com/simple" >  pip.conf
```

2. If it is because of the network, cuz it takes time to connect the source maybe:
   Try to add the following limitation after **pip install**:

```
--default-timeout=1000 --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

Update the Docker daemon

Create this file with the following: Your network’s DNS server, and for backup the Google DNS server.

/etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Then restart the docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```